# Issue when changing dpi of a tiff using Bit Miracle libtiff

Tags: libtiff, libtiff.net

I am trying to just change the resolution of a tiff image using Bit Miracle libtiff. Below is the code snippet. When I do this, tiff image resolution is changed, but the other tiff parameters are gone and I am unable to open the tiff file. Could you please help if I am doing something wrong here?

```
using (Tiff image = Tiff.Open(fileName, "a"))
{
 image.SetField(TiffTag.XRESOLUTION, 200);
 image.SetField(TiffTag.YRESOLUTION, 300);
 image.WriteDirectory();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that changing `TiffTag.XRESOLUTION` or `TiffTag.YRESOLUTION` won't change image data and will only change the way the data is interpreted by viewers or printers.

As for the code itself, you should:

- Call `SetDirectory(0)` before calling `SetField` methods. That's because you open file in append mode.
- Use `RewriteDirectory` instead of `WriteDirectory`. Otherwise you might corrupt image data.